# Missing Dictionary Value from Webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib, finance

I am making a stock screener that gets technicals from yahoo finance. 
The program creates a dictionary with all the technicals that shows up on the statistics page. I am a bit confused because is does not have the 'Price/Book' value, even though it follows the same html format as other technicals that are included, such as 'Return on Equity'.

I am a bit confused because is does not have the 'Price/Book' value, even though it follows the same html format as other technicals, such as 'Return on Equity'.

```
def scrape_yahoo(stock):
    technicals = {}
    try:
        url = ('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s='+stock)
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        tables = soup.findAll('table', {"class" : 'table-qsp-stats'})    # Found using page inspection
        for table in tables:
            table_body = table.find('tbody')
            rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

            for row in rows:
                col_name = row.find_all('span')                            # Use span to avoid supscripts
                col_name = [cell.text.strip() for cell in col_name]
                col_val = row.find_all('td')
                col_val = [cell.text.strip() for cell in col_val]
                technicals[col_name[0]] = col_val[1]                    # col_val[0] is the name cell (with subscript)
        return technicals
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed, exception: ', str(e))



def scrape(stock_list, interested, technicals):
    SuggestedStocks = []
    for each_stock in stock_list:
        technicals = scrape_yahoo(each_stock)
        condition_1 = float(technicals.get('Return on Equity',0).replace('%','').replace('N/A','-100')) > 25
        condition_2 = float(technicals.get('Trailing P/E',0).replace('N/A','0')) < 25
        condition_3 = float(technicals.get('Price/Book(mrq)',0)) <8
        condition_4 = float(technicals.get('Beta (3Y Monthly)',0)) <1.1
        if condition_1 and condition_2 and condition_3 and condition_4:
            print(each_stock)

            SuggestedStocks.append(each_stock)  
            for ind in interested: 

                print(ind + ": "+ technicals[ind])         
            print("------")
            time.sleep(1)   
                                               # Use delay to avoid getting flagged as bot
    #return technicals
    print(SuggestedStocks)


def main():

    stock_list = ['MMM', 'ABT', 'ABBV', 'ABMD', 'ACN', 'ATVI', 'ADBE', 'AMD', 'AAP', 'AES', 'AMG', 'AFL', 'A', 'APD', 'AKAM', 'ALK', 'ALB', 'ARE', 'ALXN', 'ALGN', 'ALLE', 'AGN', 'ADS', 'LNT', 'ALL', 'GOOGL', 'GOOG', 'MO', 'AMZN', 'AMCR', 'AEE', 'AAL', 'AEP', 'AXP', 'AIG']
    interested = ['Return on Equity', 'Revenue', 'Quarterly Revenue Growth','Trailing P/E', 'Beta (3Y Monthly)']#,'Price/Book(mrq)']
    technicals = {}

    tech = scrape(stock_list, interested, technicals)
    print(tech)

main()
```

KeyError: 'Price/Book(mrq)', I understand what this error means, my main question is why is this value not added to the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the field on the page is "Price/Book (mrq)" instead of "Price/Book(mrq)", you missed a space.

Comment: I added a space, and it still gives me KeyError: 'Price/Book (mrq)'

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Under the html code, the field is labeled 'Price/Book. Thanks for the help!'